# Disable add to cart button via custom checkbox in WooCommerce product settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

We want to prevent add to cart for certain upcoming products.

We want to have a checkbox to select the specific product on which we want to prevent add to cart. We have right now the checkbox and save code.

I also found this: [Remove add cart button in Woocommerce for a specific product category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660835/remove-add-cart-button-in-woocommerce-for-a-specific-product-category) and https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/the-right-way-to-hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce/

I'm not sure, what is the best way to prevent add to cart for specific products.
Does anyone have a suggestion what the best way would be?

```php
// Add new checkbox to product edit page (General tab)
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'upcoming_checkbox_to_products' );        
  
function upcoming_checkbox_to_products() {           
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
'id' => 'custom_upcoming', 
'class' => '', 
'label' => 'Prevent add to cart'
) 
);      
}
  
// -----------------------------------------
// Save checkbox via custom field
  
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_upcoming_checkbox_to_post_meta' );
  
function save_upcoming_checkbox_to_post_meta( $product_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['custom_upcoming'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_upcoming', $_POST['custom_upcoming'] );
    } else delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_upcoming' );
}

// -----------------------------------------
// Prevent add to cart
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Explanation via comment tags added in the code

To add a checkbox to the inventory product options, use:

```php
// Add checkbox
function action_woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data() {
    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
        'id'             => '_prevent_add_to_cart_button', // Required, it's the meta_key for storing the value (is checked or not)
        'label'          => __( 'My label', 'woocommerce' ), // Text in the editor label
        'desc_tip'       => false, // true or false, show description directly or as tooltip
        'description'    => __( 'Prevent add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) // Provide something useful here
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'action_woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 10, 0 );
        
// Save Field
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    // Isset, yes or no
    $checkbox = isset( $_POST['_prevent_add_to_cart_button'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

    // Update meta
    $product->update_meta_data( '_prevent_add_to_cart_button', $checkbox );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );
```

---

To disable the add to cart button for simple and variable products, use:

```php
// Is_purchasable (simple)
function filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // Get meta
    $hide_add_to_cart_button = $product->get_meta( '_prevent_add_to_cart_button' );
    
    // Compare
    if ( $hide_add_to_cart_button == 'yes' ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );

// Is_purchasable (variable)
function filter_woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $hide_add_to_cart_button = get_post_meta( $product->get_parent_id(), '_prevent_add_to_cart_button', true );

    // Compare
    if ( $hide_add_to_cart_button == 'yes' ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'filter_woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

**Note:** There are several ways to disable/remove the add to cart button, so it depends on whether you want to hide or disable the button completely.